# elasticsearch find documents that missing or have particular value

Tags: elasticsearch

I wonder how do I filter documents in elastic search that doesn't have particular field or have this field with particular value.

example, I have a doc which may have the field "only2".
and I query for all the docs, that have this field equals to my username and the whole the docs that are not set to my username (meaning I set it to be public)

Comment: Please share your efforts so far, have you tried anything?

Comment: please share scenario of your case to make us understand clear!

Comment: I added a scenario.